# Map out longitude and latitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapping, latitude-longitude

I have a "map" that shows POI's that are defined by longitude and latitude. Can I somehow figure out with these two values where exactly to put a dot representing a POI relative to the user's position ? I have thought about something like this:

Let's say the user's position is longitude = 12.3456789 and latitude = 98.7654321 and the shop would be something like longitude = 12.2345678 and latitude = 98.6543210. (Imaginary values) Is it possible to map these shops onto a rectangular area (just like google maps) ?

I am using iOS, so if you have any references it would be helpful if they were C oriented, JAVA and Obj-C should be OK too.

Comment: Using `MKMapView`? What do these locations have to do with the user location? Have you tried adding annotations to a map?

Comment: @Wain I do not use an official library or something. I would just like to visualise these dots in a uiview in respect to the user's location.

Comment: So you want to use mathematics to determine the angle and distance between the points and show that information on a view?

Comment: @Wain Yep, that's pretty much it....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to learn about the lat long calculations. Apple will help with some things, like if you use `CLLocation` you can use the `distanceFromLocation` method.

Once you have the distances and angles you will probably want to normalise the distances to a unit circle so they are easier to map into the coordinate system of your view. You could then add subviews to represent each location and set their positions based on the normalised distance and angle from the center (which represents the user), or you could implement `drawRect` and draw lines / circles to show the positions.

Comment: oh I have heard of the haversine formula! looks promising! I'll take a look and I'll give some feedback tomorrow. Thank you very much, Wain

Comment: Ok, I am not quite sure if this is correct, but it looks like it is. For small distances the equirectangular approximation delivers acceptable results. That way I get a vector and that lets me draw the point at the appropriate location. I will double-check that tomorrow, but your link has helped me a lot thank you!